# How I can to update a row dbf file from C#?

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, dbf, pdb-files

I have a table in a `.dbf` file, and I want to update a row or more than one row, but when I run the project and execute command query, I get the exception:

> ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase Driver] External table is not in the expected format.

Comment: Please add the code you are using to connect to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution to my error.

Comment: This question should not be put on hold. The problem and the solution is clear enough to understand from the error message.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void updateValesPonyNumeroFactura(ref string error)
    {
        string pathFile = @"c:\Temp\";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GetConnection(pathFile));
        try
        {

            string updateRow = $"UPDATE vale.dbf SET Factura = 'c00001' WHERE vale = '011395'";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(updateRow, con);

            con.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "MyTable");
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }



    private static string GetConnection(string path)
    {
        return $"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source={path};Collating Sequence=machine;";
    }
```

Here is the solution, I dont know if the dataset is necesary, but it works.

Edit (Cetin Basoz)
Disclaimer: I couldn't write this as an answer since, unfortunately, it was put on hold. I am adding this to explain why and few other details.

Your original code doesn't work because you used ODBC connection and the table you are using was a version later than 6. Last ODBC driver for VFP supports structures up to including 6.

Second, in your code using a DataSet nor an DataAdapter is necessary. Using a DataAdapter in fact might cause your update to fail because implicit command builders do not write the insert, update codes correctly all the time. Here is a revised version of your update. Also in this code, instead of hardcoding the values to be updated, the values are passed via parameters (which should be the case in real world scenarios):

```
private void updateValesPonyNumeroFactura(ref string error)
{
    string pathFile = @"c:\Temp\";
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(GetConnection(pathFile)))
    {
        try
        {

            string updateRow = $"UPDATE vale SET Factura = ? WHERE vale = ?";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(updateRow, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add('factura', OleDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add('vale', OleDbType.VarChar);

            cmd.Parameters['factura'].Value = "c00001";
            cmd.Parameters['vale'].Value = "011395";

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with OleDb parameter placeholders are just ? marks and they are bound by the order they are added to the parameters collection. Parameter names are just helpers to the developer (first ? binds to 'factura' parameter, second to 'vale' and so on - aka positional parameters).